# Printing multiple attributes

Tags: c#, sql, arrays, file, io

I have this program, where i need to print out the attributes of multiple goods (vare). The problem i am having is that it only prints out the attributes of a single item multiple times. I tried putting the attributes into a 2-dimensional array, but it still prints out the same attributes. My output file is a .txt file. What i want, is for the program to print out a list of goods, each with their respective attributes shown. (There are 4 different items, and 6 different attributes).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace Opgave_4._1
{
  class Program
{

        static void Main()
 {
    string connString;
    connString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Occhi che guardano;Integrated Security=SSPI";

    string sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM Vare ORDER BY Vare.Varenavn";

    Console.WriteLine(sqlstring);

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, conn);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    string att1;
    decimal att2;
    int att3;
    string att4;
    int att5;
    string att6;
    string[,] vareliste = new string[10, 10];
    StreamWriter Stream = null;
    String UdFil = "C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Desktop\\text.txt";
    Stream = new StreamWriter(UdFil);
    try
    { 
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            if (Reader.IsDBNull(0))
                att1 = "hej";
            else
                att1 = Reader.GetString(0);
            if (Reader.IsDBNull(1))
                att2 = 0.0006000M;
            else
                att2 = Reader.GetDecimal(1);
            if (Reader.IsDBNull(2))
                att3 = 12;
            else
                att3 = Reader.GetInt32(2);
            if (Reader.IsDBNull(3))
                att4 = "hej";
            else
                att4 = Reader.GetString(3);
            if (Reader.IsDBNull(4))
                att5 = 14;
            else
                att5 = Reader.GetInt32(4);
            if (Reader.IsDBNull(5))
                att6 = "hejsa";
            else
                att6 = Reader.GetString(5);




            Stream.WriteLine(att1 + " " + att2 + " " + att3 + " " + att4 + " " + att5 + " " + att6);

            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fejl i sti  {0}", e.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (Stream != null)
                    Stream.Close();
            }


        }

    }

    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Reader.Close(); // luk ResultSet
        conn.Close(); // luk connection igen
    }
```

}

```
    }
}
```

And here is the print output (edited (after removing finally clause)):

1234                 1200,0000 5 Aviator                        1111 Raiban
1234                 1200,0000 5 Aviator                        1111 Raiban
1234                 1200,0000 5 Aviator                        1111 Raiban
4321                 110,0000 6 Femme                          1111 Hindberg
4321                 110,0000 6 Femme                          1111 Hindberg
4321                 110,0000 6 Femme                          1111 Hindberg
3241                 500,0000 2 Pilot-etui                     3333 Raiban
3241                 500,0000 2 Pilot-etui                     3333 Raiban
3241                 500,0000 2 Pilot-etui                     3333 Raiban
1423                 250,0000 30 Splash                         4444 Lensway
1423

(If i use an integer less than 3 in the for loop, it does not print anything for some reason)

The data in the table is

Pris = price. Lager = storage. Antal = Amount. Gruppe = Group. Mærke = Brand

```
+---------+----------+-----------------+------------+---------------+-----------+
| Vare_id | Varepris | VareLager_antal |  Varenavn  | Varegruppe_nr | Varemærke |
+---------+----------+-----------------+------------+---------------+-----------+
|    1234 | 1200     |               5 | Aviator    |          1111 | Raiban    |
|    1423 | 250      |              30 | Splash     |          4444 | Lensway   |
|    3241 | 500      |               2 | Pilot-etui |          3333 | Raiban    |
|    4321 | 110      |               6 | Femme      |          1111 | Hindberg  |
+---------+----------+-----------------+------------+---------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new `StreamWriter` for each iteration means you overwrite your file each time. You'll only end up with the last record in here.

Reading the same field four times for each iteration is going to return the same thing each time. The recordset only moves on when you call `Reader.Read()`

You should try and use `using` statements to control cleanup of your resources. For example

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
    using (StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(UdFil)) {
        while (Reader.Read()) {
           ....
        }
    }
}
```

This will close the `Connection` and `StreamWriter` appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! But where would you put the call for "Reader.Read() ? And about the StreamWriter, i thought it was outside the iteration, since it is called outside the for loop.

Comment: You already have an outer loop that uses `While(Reader.Read())`. This will run once per row in the result set. Your stream is created inside this loop.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. so you want to me to call the Streamwriter outside the while loop?

Comment: I think "want" is the wrong word. I want you to understand why you get these results. If you now think putting the `StreamWriter` outside the loop will help, you should try it and see.

Comment: I tried that, and now i get the same result as before, but instead of getting it once, i get it three times. That i do not understand.

Comment: I have a table consisting of 4 different items with the total of 6 attributes being: Vare_id, Varepris, VareLager_antal, Varenavn, Varegruppe_nr, Varemærke. Pris = price. Lager = storage. Antal = Amount. Gruppe = Group. Mærke = Brand. The vare_id has the following values: 1234, 1423, 3241, 4321. Varepris: 1200, 250, 500, 110. VareLager_antal: 5, 30, 2, 6. Varenavn: Aviator, Splash, Pilot-etui, Femme. Varegruppe_nr: 1111, 4444, 3333, 1111. Varemærke: Raiban, Lensway, Raiban, Hindberg.

Comment: You're right it does throw an exception: "Cannot write to a closed text writer".

Comment: I have added the new output after removing the finally clause for the stream writer.

Comment: Basically i want the output to be shown as the values in the table you edited into my question. (Without the borders).

Comment: Ok, so i deleted the array and edited the for loop. I have added the for loop and output in the question.

Comment: Yes, it is now up again. Ok, so i removed the for loop and now it does not give an output.

Comment: You need to close the stream outside the `while (Reader.Read())` loop. A `finally` clause would be appropriate. Don't be afraid to overwrite the question. People who are interested in the history can look through the edits.

Comment: When i put the finally clause outside the while loop, i get this error: "Cannot write to a closed text writer"

Comment: @user1696992 I've updated the answer to describe the using construct.